# query returning multidimensional grouped arrays

Tags: mysql, group-concat

In the hypothetical scenario where I have a couple of database tables, in a one to many relationship. I am trying to find a nice query function so that I can return each row in table A with a nested array for all the linked rows from table B.

```
SELECT a.id AS id,a.name as name,b.id AS b_id,b.name AS b_name FROM a,b WHERE a.id=b.eid;
```

will return only one result

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.name as name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS b_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) AS b_name 
FROM a,b 
WHERE a.id = b.eid;
```

whereas this returns what I want but I'm after an array not a string (there might be commas in b.name)

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the linked key? is b.id a foreign key?

Comment: thats a good point linked key would be something else - b.eid, I've updated this in above query

Comment: could you be more precise what would want to accomplish...
as i understand it you should use explode()?

Comment: Yes I would use explode but there might be commas in b.name which would through the whole thing off.

Comment: you can change the separator 
add SEPARATOR 'seperatorsign here'

just noticed someone already replied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separator different from comma:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(b.name SEPARATOR ';') AS b_name
```

Comment: Yes perfect, cheers, just thought of that myself. Out of curiosity if one can't guarantee that any character or combination of characters won't be in the value b_name. Are the any other methods?

Comment: well you could use a really long and random separator, they'll be gone anyways once you explode it make it 3 signs long and i doubt they ever get confused with regular text
a good seperator "#&£" =D

Comment: You can escape existing separator char with other separator char: `GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(b.name,';',';;') SEPARATOR ';') AS b_name` but this requires also a special treatment when using the data.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to return anything other than a MySQL datatype, so the short answer is no you cannot return a array (nested or otherwise) of results from a subquery. You'll also see some pretty drastic performance hits trying to build string concatenated values from the foreign, the sub-string order will be implicit and, as you've alluded to, you'll have problems selecting a suitable delimiter.

It almost certainly going to be more efficient use a simple JOIN to create a single result set. Any duplicates on the "one" side of the relationship should be handled programmatically (which is preferable, in any sense, to handling string splitting on multiple concatenated fields).